# load everything on a page (css, .js, etc files) before scraping

Tags: javascript, php, css, class, curl

I want to ask if someone has an idea how to load the page completely (like all the css, .js etc files) before scraping the page. My goal in doing this is that, I want to scrape a page where the value I want to get is given by a js file. I am using php curl to POST data, and using simple hmtl dom parser to easily get the data I want but the parser can't seem to detect/get that value, I suspected that the parser is not getting that because the page is not completely loaded.

I hope anyone has an idea.

Thank you.

EDIT : 
here is the function I use for the parser

```
foreach($dom->find("div[class=ResultItem Registered]") as $element)
```

it can't find the second class "Registered", because it is being given a .js file.

Comment: What about making a function which is called after you get to the point where the object has been added?

Comment: I don't know how to call a function when the page completely loads after the curl is done. I even use sleep(), return / exit function just to wait until complete then parse the page.

Comment: There is a point in your code where the object has been added, place the function call after that.

Comment: _“I suspected that the parser is not getting that because the page is not completely loaded”_ – no, it is because the parser is a simple _parser_, and not a _browser_ that would request or execute any JavaScript. You need the latter – a browser, or at least something like it – to get this to work; “headless browser” is a research keyword.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe and @David for the advice. In my case I found an answer, I used jquery . I just found out that the this function (" `$(document).ready(function(){ });` ") do something inside it when the document is ready, when the whole page is completely loaded. I just searched the whole document for the value I looked for. thanks everyone.